# how to check which option the intent installation the user pressed? android

Tags: android, android-intent, installation

I have a code that install a application from of a apk.
I want to know, which option the user selected "Install" or "Cancel" in intent.

Is possible?

I'm using AsyncTask. I wanted to do this verification method onPostExecute, but this method is called before of the installation is complete.

Comment: Post the code you have written so far.

Comment: code is the installation application for a apk. What I want is which option button the user selected.

Comment: Oh, yes, ok, I get the point now. So I am useless for that question.